# Flutter Moor: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFormTemplates' of null

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to build a multi-platform local database in flutter using moor to support both web and mobile and desktop. I have managed to create the logic to create the database and set it it up for web and mobile. For some weird reason the data is not being inserted am not sure what am doing wrong.

this is what I have done so far

creating the database

```
// this will generate a table called "forms" for us. The rows of that table will
// be represented by a class called "Forms".
// general information about form
// forms
@DataClassName("DbForm")
class Forms extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text()();
  TextColumn get form_name => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get section_names => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get data_content => text()();
  TextColumn get updated_by => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get date_created => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get date_updated => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get user_location => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get imei => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get server_id => text().nullable()();
  BoolColumn get synced => boolean().nullable()();
  TextColumn get facility => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get dateOfSurvey => text().nullable()();

  @override
  Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id};
}

// form_templates
class FormTemplates extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text()();
  TextColumn get form_name => text().customConstraint(
      "UNIQUE")(); // each form should have its own name (there can't be 2 BAISV forms lol)
  TextColumn get form_content => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get form_sections => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get server_id => text().nullable()();
  BoolColumn get synced => boolean().nullable()();

  @override
  Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id};
}

// incident_reports
class IncidentReports extends Table {
  TextColumn get id => text()();
  TextColumn get formName => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get dateCreated => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get dateUpdated => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get updatedBy => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get userLocation => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get imei => text().nullable()();
  TextColumn get dataContent => text().nullable()();
  BoolColumn get approved => boolean().nullable()();
  BoolColumn get synced => boolean().nullable()();

  @override
  Set<Column> get primaryKey => {id};
}

// this annotation tells moor to prepare a database class that uses both of the
// tables we just defined. We'll see how to use that database class in a moment.
@UseMoor(tables: [
  Forms,
  FormTemplates,
  IncidentReports
])
class FormsDatabase extends _$FormsDatabase {

  FormsDatabase(QueryExecutor e) : super(e);
  final cs = ChangeStack();
  
  int _schemaVersion = 47;
  // you should bump this number whenever you change or add a table definition. Migrations
  // are covered later in this readme.
  @override
  int get schemaVersion => _schemaVersion;

  @override
  MigrationStrategy get migration =>
      MigrationStrategy(onUpgrade: (migrator, from, to) async {
        if (from < _schemaVersion) {
          migrator.createTable(forms);
          // migrator.createTable(formTemplates);
          // migrator.createTable(incidentReports);
        }
      });

  // singleton instance method to try and avoid multiple databases
 // static FormsDatabase getInstance() => _database;

  // get all forms
  Future<List<DbForm>> getAllForms() => select(forms).get();
  Stream<List<DbForm>> watchAllTasks() => select(forms).watch();
  Future<List<DbForm>> getUnsyncedForms() =>
      (select(forms)..where((t) => isNull(t.synced) | t.synced.equals(false)))
          .get();

  // get a specific type of form
  Future<List<DbForm>> getFormByName(String name) =>
      (select(forms)..where((t) => t.form_name.equals(name))).get();

  // get the different form types (BAISV, incident report, etc.)
  Future<List<FormTemplate>> getFormTemplates() => select(formTemplates).get();
  Future insertFormTemplate(FormTemplate template) =>
      into(formTemplates).insert(template);
  Future updateFormTemplate(FormTemplate template) =>
      (update(formTemplates)..where((t) => t.id.equals(template.id)))
          .write(template);

  // managing forms
  Future insertForm(DbForm form) =>
      into(forms).insert(form); // insert form data
  Future updateForm(DbForm form) =>
      (update(forms)..where((t) => t.id.equals(form.id)))
          .write(form); // update form data
  Future deleteForm(DbForm form) =>
      delete(forms).delete(form); // delete form data

  // managing incident reports
  Future<List<IncidentReport>> getUnsyncedIncidents() =>
      (select(incidentReports)..where((t) => isNull(t.synced) | t.synced.equals(false)))
          .get();
  Future<List<IncidentReport>> getIncidentReports() => select(incidentReports).get();
  Future insertIndicentReport(IncidentReport incident) => into(incidentReports).insert(incident);
  Future updateIndicentReport(IncidentReport incident) => (update(incidentReports)
  ..where((t) => t.id.equals(incident.id))).write(incident);
  Future<FormTemplate> getTemplateByName(String name) =>
      (select(formTemplates)..where((t) => t.form_name.equals(name)))
          .getSingle();
  Future<IncidentReport> getIncidentById(String id) =>
      (select(incidentReports)..where((t) => t.formName.equals(id)))
          .getSingle();
}
```

I created a constructor to check if it is web or mobile

```
FormsDatabase constructDb({bool logStatements = false}) {
  if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
    final executor = LazyDatabase(() async {
      final dataDir = await paths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbFile = File(p.join(dataDir.path, 'db.sqlite'));
      return VmDatabase(dbFile, logStatements: logStatements);
    });
    return FormsDatabase(executor);
  }
  if (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isLinux) {
    final file = File('db.sqlite');
    return FormsDatabase(VmDatabase(file, logStatements: logStatements));
  }
  // if (Platform.isWindows) {
  //   final file = File('db.sqlite');
  //   return Database(VMDatabase(file, logStatements: logStatements));
  // }
  return FormsDatabase(VmDatabase.memory(logStatements: logStatements));
}
```

At this point am getting data from an api and inserting into the database from another class. The data specifically tied to the logged in user

```
  FormsDatabase db; //this is a global variable calling the formsclass of creating the database

      Future<bool> getFormTypes() async {
    debugPrint("getFormTypes() called");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString("username");
    // print("the username is" + email);
    try {
      var response = await http.get("http://54.32.67.51:9080/api/v1/user/$email/studies");
      print(response);
      locals = await db.getFormTemplates();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          templates = fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
          count = templates.length;
          // set local db to results
          for (FormTemplate f in templates) {
            if (!locals.contains(f)) {
              // check if locals has an item with that id
              // if yes, then the form needs to be updated
              // else, insert as new entity
              if (existsInLocalsById(f.id)) {
                db.updateFormTemplate(f);
              } else {
                db.insertFormTemplate(f);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
      // sync if connected to the internet
      bool successfulSync = await syncToServer();
      debugPrint("successfulSync is $successfulSync");
      return successfulSync;
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("SOCKETEXCEPTION IN getFormTypes()");
      debugPrint(e.message);
      // if there's no internet, load templates from local storage
      locals = await db.getFormTemplates();
      setState(() {
        templates = locals;
        count = templates.length;
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
```